# Need to vectorize function that using loop (replace NA rows with values from vector)

Tags: r, vector, matrix, na

How I can rewrite this function to vectorized variant. As I know, using loops are not good practice in R:

```
# replaces rows that contains all NAs with non-NA values from previous row and K-th column
na.replace <- function(x, k) {
    for (i in 2:nrow(x)) {
        if (!all(is.na(x[i - 1, ])) && all(is.na(x[i, ]))) {
                x[i, ] <- x[i - 1, k]
        }
    }
    x
}
```

This is input data and returned data for function:

```
m <- cbind(c(NA,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA,6,7,8), c(NA,NA,2,3,NA,NA,NA,7,8,9))
m
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA
 [3,]    1    2
 [4,]    2    3
 [5,]   NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA
 [8,]    6    7
 [9,]    7    8
[10,]    8    9

na.replace(m, 2)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA
 [3,]    1    2
 [4,]    2    3
 [5,]    3    3
 [6,]    3    3
 [7,]    3    3
 [8,]    6    7
 [9,]    7    8
[10,]    8    9
```

Comment: Could you please state exactly what it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use vectorized solution that do the same algorithm as function above. Algorithm is simple: replace all NA rows with values from previous rows and K-th column.

Comment: Have you checked out `na.locf` in the `zoo` package?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `na.locf` doesn't work for entire rows.

Comment: @maloneypatr yes, but na.locf is not suitable. It replaces NA with previous non-NA value from the same column. But I need to decide what column I want to use for replacement.

Comment: Notice that, unless you have a pathological condition where the first row is all `NA` (in which case you're screwed anyway),  you don't need to check whether `all(is.na(x[i - 1, ]))` is T or F because in the previous time thru the loop you "fixed" row `i-1` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using `na.locf` in the zoo package.  `row.na` is a vector with one component per row of `m` such that a component is `TRUE` if the corresponding row of `m` is all `NA` and `FALSE` otherwise.  We then set all elements of such rows to the result of applying `na.locf` to column 2.

At the expense of a bit of speed the lines ending with `##` could be replaced with `row.na <- apply(is.na(m), 1, all)` which is a bit more readable.

If we knew that if any row has an `NA` in column 2 then all columns of that row are `NA`, as in the question, then the lines ending in `##` could be reduced to just `row.na <- is.na(m[, 2])`

```
library(zoo)

nr <- nrow(m) ##
nc <- ncol(m) ##

row.na <- .rowSums(is.na(m), nr, nc) == nc ##

m[row.na, ] <- na.locf(m[, 2], na.rm = FALSE)[row.na]
```

The result is:

```
> m
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA
 [3,]    1    2
 [4,]    2    3
 [5,]    3    3
 [6,]    3    3
 [7,]    3    3
 [8,]    6    7
 [9,]    7    8
[10,]    8    9
```

**REVISED** Some revisions to improve speed as in comments below.  Also added alternatives in discussion.

Comment: Thanks. Seems your solution can be more efficient:
 
    `row.na <- apply(m, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))`
    `m[row.na, ] <- na.locf(m[, 2], na.rm = F)[row.na]`

Comment: I would expect putting the m[,2] in na.locf would be faster but the apply in the answer should be faster because is.na is only called once rather than once per column.  I have tested the various combinations and modified the answer to the fastest I found.

Comment: if you are concerned about speed, then do `rowSums(is.na(m)) == ncol(m)` rather than `apply(is.na(m), 1, all)`.

Comment: Good point.  `row.na <- .rowSums(is.na(m), nrow(m), ncol(m)) == ncol(m)` is faster still.

Answer (score 2):

The most important part in this answer is getting the grouping you want, which is:

```
groups = cumsum(rowSums(is.na(m)) != ncol(m))
groups
#[1] 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 5
```

Once you have that the rest is just doing your desired operation by group, e.g.:

```
library(data.table)

dt = as.data.table(m)

k = 2
cond = rowSums(is.na(m)) != ncol(m)
dt[, (k) := .SD[[k]][1], by = cumsum(cond)]
dt[!cond, names(dt) := .SD[[k]]]
dt
#    V1 V2
# 1: NA NA
# 2: NA NA
# 3:  1  2
# 4:  2  3
# 5:  3  3
# 6:  3  3
# 7:  3  3
# 8:  6  7
# 9:  7  8
#10:  8  9
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution looks heavyweight and using third-party package.

Comment: I suspect it *is* heavyweight, but the base-only restriction is a handicap you should not impose on yourself without extremely good reasons. R wouldn't be what it is without third-party packages. I'm curious if you have any real-size examples to play around with?

Comment: @EldarAgalarov I modified the solution to be more modular and simpler

Comment: Thanks, your solution returns correct output. I never used "data.table" package so I have troubles with reading and understanding of your code :) For me is better to use base-only structures as much as possible.

Comment: If you're using R for any "big data (frames)", data.table is a critical package worth knowing in depth.  IMO, data.table should be part of 'base R'

Comment: Now I understand that "data.table" is great package and works much faster than "data.frame" functions family. As said above, this package must be included into base.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that, unless you have a pathological condition where the first row is all NANA (in which case you're screwed anyway),  you don't need to check whether all(is.na(x[i−1,]))all(is.na(x[i - 1, ])) is T or F because in the previous time thru the loop you "fixed" row i−1i-1 .
Further, all you care about is that the designated `k-th` value is not `NA`. The rest of the row doesn't matter.

BUT: The k-th value always "falls through" from the top, so perhaps you should:

1) treat the k-th column as a vector, e.g.  `c(NA,1,NA,NA,3,NA,4,NA,NA)` and "fill-down" all numeric values.  That's been done many times on SO questions.

2) Every row which is entirely `NA` except for column `k` gets filled with that same value.
I think that's still best done using either a loop or `apply`

You probably need to clarify whether some rows have both numeric and NA values, which your example fails to include.  If that's the case, then things get trickier.

Comment: Rows can contain only all NAs or only all numeric values. Thank You for idea, I realized now vectorized solution and it works fine. I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base only vectorized approach:

```
na.replace <- function(x, k) {
   is.all.na <- rowSums(is.na(x)) == ncol(x)
   ref.idx <- cummax((!is.all.na) * seq_len(nrow(x)))
   ref.idx[ref.idx == 0] <- NA
   x[is.all.na, ] <- x[ref.idx[is.all.na], k]
   x
}
```

And for fair comparison with @Eldar's solution, replace `is.all.na` with `is.all.na <- is.na(x[, k])`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I realized my version of vectorized solution and it works as expected. Any comments and suggestions are welcome :)

```
# Last Observation Move Forward
# works as na.locf but much faster and accepts only 1D structures
na.lomf <- function(object, na.rm = F) {
    idx <- which(!is.na(object))
    if (!na.rm && is.na(object[1])) idx <- c(1, idx)
    rep.int(object[idx], diff(c(idx, length(object) + 1)))
}    

na.replace <- function(x, k) {
    v <- x[, k]
    i <- which(is.na(v))
    r <- na.lomf(v)
    x[i, ] <- r[i]
    x
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Here's a workaround with the `na.locf` function from `zoo`:

```
m[na.locf(ifelse(apply(m, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))), NA, 1:nrow(m)), na.rm=F),]

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA
 [3,]    1    2
 [4,]    2    3
 [5,]    2    3
 [6,]    2    3
 [7,]    2    3
 [8,]    6    7
 [9,]    7    8
[10,]    8    9
```

Comment: Your variant returns wrong result. Rows 5,6,7 must be (3, 3) but not (2, 3).